# Adding a border below Toolbar android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-toolbar

I'm trying to add a border that would look like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGMXE.jpg

My toolbar.xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
android:elevation="1dp"
app:theme="@style/AppTheme"
app:titleTextAppearance="@style/TitleText"
app:titleTextColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"

>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

In my java code I do :
`toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);`
`setSupportActionBar(toolbar);`
and inflating the menu.

If I try to nest the toolbar in relative/linear/constrains layout and add a View at the bottom I get the "android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar" error

Also tried to `<include` a layout with a View inside of it, but then the line appears in the middle of my toolbar and my title disappears.

Also including my menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
android:id="@+id/item1"
android:icon="@drawable/main_btn_info"
android:title="Item 1"
app:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create toolbar inside Linear Layout with a view

   ```
   <LinearLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"

      <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar    
      android:id="@+id/toolbar_main"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
      android:elevation="1dp"
      app:theme="@style/AppTheme"
      app:titleTextAppearance="@style/TitleText"
      app:titleTextColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"/>

      <View 
      android:background="your border color"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="2dp" />

   </LinearLayout>
   ```
2. Include this in all your layouts.
3. Then find toolbar in activity using toolbar id instead of xml name

   ```
   toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_main); 
   setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the elevation parameter

```
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_login"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    app:title="Log In"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    app:titleTextColor="#000000" />
```

> android:elevation="5dp"

This gives you out an basic elevation border bottom shadow for Toolbar

Answer (score 1):

I used this method:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:title="Setting"
        app:titleTextColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:background="#DDD" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Made another layout with the border and included it in every activity, I know it's not the best way to do it, but result is the same for now.